# Calling SUBST from Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, subst

I have problem calling SUBST from a Windows batch file. I want to use one batch to create a virtual drive mapping and a second batch to unmount the drive. However unmounting gives the error message:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Here are my batch files:

**prepare.bat**

```
pushd .
subst X: .
X:
```

**cleanup.bat**

```
popd
subst X: /D
```

Execution give the following outputs:

```
d:\>prepare.bat

d:\>pushd .

d:\>subst X: .

d:\>X:

X:\>cleanup.bat

X:\>popd

d:\>subst X: /D
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

d:\>
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong here and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Some strange things to notice:

- Typing all commands directly to the console works. Only when using
  batch files, the error occurs.
- Directly before calling `subst X: /D` the drive mapping is fine. Directly after calling it, the drive mapping has indeed been removed. Yet why do I get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that behaviour is the way a batch script is executed. It reads a line, executes it and reads the next line to execute until there are no more lines.

When you unmount the drive, you destroy the (virtual) path to the script, so "reading the next line" fails - the script is "gone". Even if the unmount is the very last line of the script, the interpreter doesn't know until it tries to read the next line - and fails, because the script is not available any more.

So your error message doesn't come from anything inside your script, but from the interpreter itself, trying to read the next line of the script.

If you enter the command at the command prompt, there is no "next line" expected, so no error occurs.

**Edit**

to avoid the errormessage:

```
subst x: /d & goto :eof
```

The line is read and parsed in one go, and as *this* line exits the batch explicitely, the interpreter doesn't try to read the *next* line.

Comment: Better explain than me, you can take the accpeted anser check.

Comment: @tukan it's up to Juergen to accept the answer that helped him most. Imagine, we could just "take" the checkmark - LOL - What a mess would that be...

Comment: hehe, true that would be one hell of a mess :).

Comment: @Stephan That workaround is a great idea and suits my needs very well! I'll go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: EDIT: I tried it out and it just generates a second error message. However, the explanation is clear.

Comment: out of curiosity: what error message? (I'm German too, so just copy/paste it)

Comment: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

Comment: hm - right - when `cleanup` is executed from `X:` (without `popd`). With `popd` there is no error. Also no error when executed like `X:\>D:cleanup` (with or without `popd`). It looks like my assumptions weren't correct. Let me think about it...